# Storing data in JobExecutionContext between steps

Tags: spring-batch

I want to store data in the job execution context so it can be shared between steps.

In order to get hold of the context, I put this annotation in the item processor

```
@Value("#{jobExecutionContext}") JobExecution context;
```

But this exception is thrown

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'jobExecutionContext' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:246) 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:112) 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:107) 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:93) 
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:89) 
        at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind `#{jobExecutionContext}` directly using `@Value`; you need a `JobExecutionListener` for that.